# JSON or blob? how do I select when I met array data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I doing a drone project that I want to save drone flight path.

as title, I have a column that needs to save an array coordinate data.

my schema:
[image]

I save the data through serialization temporarily, but I' not sure that's a good idea, maybe I should use JSON? Or I should use NoSQL？

Or is there any better way to solve this kind of problem？

Comment: AFAIK BLOB can store JSON easily. The only difference which makes sense to consider - JSON type field is "formalized", so selected value may be resorted while compare with saved value. And there is more easy to create generated/indexed fields if needed. So think what is more safe for your application firstly.

Comment: so in your view, I should save JSON array, not array?

Comment: Either array or object. If the data is plain (one level, no nested data) and named parameters not needed use array else object.